# Trying to set custom label while sending mail using API

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am trying to set a custom label to the mail sent from my app so that I would be able to filter and show only mails whose label contains the custom label set by me while sending mail.

I am using the below api for sending mail :

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send`

The request body is as follows :

```
  "raw": "RnJvbToga2ZhaXl5YXo5M0BnbWFpbC5jb20KVG86IGtmYWl5eWF6OTNAZ21haWwuY29tClN1YmplY3Q6IFNheWluZyBIZWxsbwoKVGhpcyBpcyBhIG1lc3NhZ2UganVzdCB0byBzYXkgaGVsbG8u",
  "labelIds": [
    "Label_6560641426187717823",
    "UNREAD",
    "SENT",
    "INBOX"
  ]
}
```

`Label_6560641426187717823` is the id of the custom label

But the response given by the api does not contain the custom label id.

The response of the api is as follows :

```
{
 "id": "171cfafd736aa120",
 "threadId": "171cfafd736aa120",
 "labelIds": [
  "UNREAD",
  "SENT",
  "INBOX"
 ]
}
```

Please can anyone help me what is the issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

To add or remove the labels we need to send the message and then use the modify message API with the message id returned in the send message response & in the body of modify message API, we need to send array of addLabelIds or removeLabelIds respectively.